# WPF app runs on command line

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF app. I want to use the same app in command line also. I did the following if args.Length > 0

```
AttachConsole(-1);
Console.WriteLine("Start");
Console.WriteLine("Stop");
FreeConsole();
```

It give me o/p like that

```
C:\Work>TestWriteCLI.exe -h
C:\Work>Start
Stop
```

The problem is that it does not returns to next command prompt until i press and Enter.
I tried AllocConsole() ebut it create a new console which i don't want. I want the o/p should 
be like this:

```
C:\Work>TestWriteCLI.exe -h
Start
Stop
C:\Work>
```

Comment: the last line you want means the current state should be ***some console is currently attached***, but using FreeConsole() of course will free that state. Why don't you try running some `cd` command to move the current working path to `C:\Work`? Although I'm not sure what actually you want.

Comment: For what it's worth, the issue isn't that the console isn't returning to the command prompt. It's that it _already_ has returned to the command prompt before your code starts writing to the console. After "Stop" is shown, you could enter a new command without pressing `Enter` and it would still work. Not that that addresses the visual issue you're concerned with, but it might reframe the problem in a way that's useful to you.

Comment: my concern is: after program exit, command prompt is not returning